# Handling Exception in multiprocess

Tags: python, python-2.7, exception, multiprocessing

I have 2 processes `A` and `B`, communicating through a `multiprocessing.Pipe()`, and I would like raise an exception in `B` when `A` fails.
For now I have something like that:

```
def A_function():
    try:
        a,b=Pipe()
        B=Process(target=B_function,args=(b,))
        B.start()
        while True:
            a.send(data)
            data_recv=a.recv()
    except Exception as e:
        print e
        #  terminate process properly

def B_function(b):
    try:
        while True:
            data_recv=b.recv()
            # do some work on data_recv, but can fail
            b.send(modified_data)
    except Exception as e:
        print e
        raise # not working on the other process `A`

A=Process(target=A_function)
A.start()
```

If process `B` fails, there is nothing happening on `A`. I wonder if there is a pythonic way to transmit the exception to `A` or if I should send some dummy message through the `Pipe`, or kill the Pipe to raise an Error in `A`, but that doesn't seem very clean.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AFAIK you need to send your own message through the pipe. It seems like you
want to send exception from `B` to `A`. The code in `B` for exception
handling could be like this:

```
class RemoteException(object):
    def __init__(self, exc, err_string, tb):
        self.exception = exc
        self.error_string = err_string
        self.tb = tb

try:
    data_recv = b.recv()
except Exception:
    exception, error_string, tb = sys.exc_info()
    b.send(RemoteException(exception, error_string, tb))
    ...
```

In `A`:

```
while True:
    ..
    data_recv = a.recv()
    if isinstance(data_recv, RemoteException):
        raise data_recv.error_string, None, data_recv.tb
```

Of course both `A` and `B` processes should share the same `RemoteException` class.

Comment: That should also work without creating the `RemoteException`, no? I could simply send the `e` and use your `if isinstance(e,Exception):` to raise the Exception in `A`. I will try that tomorrow. Thanks for your help!